# How safe is front end with react and redux?

Tags: security, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am wondering this for a while now when I am building react and redux applications. How easy is it for a person to change the redux and/or react state manually? I can't find documentation on this anywhere and would love to know the security issues etc.

**Example of a redux state**

```
{
    firstName: 'Foo',
    lastName: 'Bar',
    permissions: {
        'admin': false
    }
}
```

Would they be able to change or influence something like the `admin` permission and set it to `true`?

And if they can change it, would it be accepted by reducers etc?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The frontend is inherently insecure. I can inject my own code any time. Setup breakpoints and manipulate variables during runtime.
With that in mind. I could put anything I wanted in a redux store and get any value out of it. This includes setting an `admin` permission/flag to `true`.
I could also trigger the reducers to run with the new value.

Comment: Thanks, and what are the ways to secure it the most / make it more secure?

Comment: "Ignore" the insecurity in the frontend and handle it in the backend. Access tokens and the likes should be stored in httpOnly secure cookies. Make sure that it doesn't matter if the user changes the `admin` permissions to `true`, because anything that requires permissions would be rejected by the backend anyways.

Comment: @NikolajDamLarsen about these tokens, are they like cookies which have a unique value and get invalid after a certain amount of time?

Comment: @NealVDV Well, the token is just some string, stored in a cookie, passed to the backend for authorization. Just like a sessionId, except the backend doesn't necessarily have to know about the token to authorize it. But that part wasn't really related to your question, though, so you can ignore that line (unless your backend uses tokens for authentication). TheSharpieOne was pretty much spot on with his answer - don't rely on the frontend for security. Everything can be manipulated by the user.